# set dataframe name inside a function using lapply

Tags: r, lapply

Let's say, for the sake of the example, that I have a list of departments. Everyone of them is on a separate table named "departmentName", so I created a list this way.

```
depts <- c("financial","sales",.....)
```

and then iterate to get members this way creating a function:

```
get.employees <- function(tablename) {

  con <- DBI::dbConnect(connectiondata....)

  query <- glue::glue("select name,position,area from {tablename}")

  assign(tablename,
         dplyr::tbl(conn, sql(query)) %>% collect())

}

lapply(depts,get.employees)
```

It works fine but It returned a list of data frames with no name assigned to every element as I was expecting.

I need every dataframe named as the department name.

Comment: `lapply(setNames(nm = depts), get.employees)`

Comment: if you do result <- lapply(depts,get.employees) than names(results) <- depts should assigne the names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Simplifying the example to use `get.employees` and `depts` in the Note at the end we can use `Map` instead of `lapply`:

```
L <- Map(get.employees, depts)
names(L)
## [1] "finance" "sales"
```

**2)** This also works:

```
L2 <- sapply(depts, get.employees, simplify = FALSE)
names(L2)
## [1] "finance" "sales"
```

### Note

Simplified example:

```
get.employees <- function(x) BOD
depts <- c("finance", "sales")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try-

```
> ls <- mapply(get.employees, depts,SIMPLIFY = F)

> names(ls)
[1] "finance" "sales"
```

**Note**- Input data was taken from answer provided by @G. Grothendleck